# How do I get each row on a separate line?

Tags: python

This program prints a table with 5 rows and 3 columns. Each row needs to be on a separate line. Use end=""

```
table = []

ROWS = 5
COLUMNS = 3
for i in range(ROWS) :
   row = [0] * COLUMNS
   table.append(row)
print(table)
```

Comment: Two ways:
1. print(*table, sep = "\n")
2. [print (val) for val in table]

Comment: @JuanBotero I am trying to learn how to use end="" with this problem so an example using that would help thanks

Comment: Using end="" replace "\n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By itself, `print()` can't put spaces between a list's elements it just calls an internal function of the `list` class to ask what it should print. Instead, you can define your own special print function like this:

```
def printTable(table):
    print('[')
    for el in table:
        print(f'  {el},')
    print(']')


table = []

ROWS = 5
COLUMNS = 3
for i in range(ROWS):
    row = [0] * COLUMNS
    table.append(row)

printTable(table)
```

You could also pass each element of the array as a separate parameter with a generator expression and use the `sep` keyword argument:

```
def printTable(table):
    print('[')
    print(*(f'  {el}' for el in table), sep="\n")
    print(']')


table = []

ROWS = 5
COLUMNS = 3
for i in range(ROWS):
    row = [0] * COLUMNS
    table.append(row)

printTable(table)
```

I also used an f-string to provide a bit of nice indentation, but this is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **tabulate** module.

```
#IMPORT TABULATE
from tabulate import tabulate

#YOUR CODE
table = []
ROWS = 5
COLUMNS = 3
for i in range(ROWS) :
   row = [0] * COLUMNS
   table.append(row)

#PRINT
print(tabulate(table))
```